# replace values by different conditions in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','BA','BA','AB','>','>','>','>'],
                       'ID2':['','','','','','','mh','mh','nn','nn']})
df_test
```

[image: df_test]

I want to obtain a dataframe like this based on the column 'ID1'(1. `if len(ID1)>2: then ID1=ID1[-1]`(for example 'BA', 'AB' will be replaced with 'A', 'B', respectively); 2. `if ID1='>': then ID1=ID2`(for example: '>' will be replaced with 'mh','nn',respectively)):

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','A','A','B','mh','mh','nn','nn']})
df_result
```

[image: df_result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` accessor:

```
out = df['ID1'].str[-1].replace('>', np.nan).fillna(df['ID2']).to_frame()
print(out)

# Output
  ID1
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   A
4   A
5   B
6  mh
7  mh
8  nn
9  nn
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.str[-1]` regardless of the length of the strings in the column to select the last character, and use `<column>.where(cond, other_col)` to fill in values that don't match `cond` with those values from `other_col`:

```
df_test['ID1'] = df_test.assign(ID1=df_test['ID1'].str[-1]).pipe(lambda x: x['ID1'].where(x['ID1'] != '>', x['ID2']))
```

Comment: (This was originally the first answer, but I lost internet right before posting :/)

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `mask`

```
df_test.ID1.mask(df_test.ID1.eq('>'),df_test.ID2,inplace=True)
df_test
Out[217]: 
  ID1 ID2
0   A    
1   B    
2   C    
3  BA    
4  BA    
5  AB    
6  mh  mh
7  mh  mh
8  nn  nn
9  nn  nn
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not replace BA and AB to A and B